# Как правильно сохранить данные в Shapefile после их считывания с файлов?

Tags: python, pyshp

У меня есть 2 файла, в которых есть данные.
Я хочу проходится по этим файлам и по заданной мне логике, сохранять данные в `Shapefile`. 
Вот как я это делаю:

```
import shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer('polygon')
with open('long_1_double.txt', 'r') as long:
    for i in long:
            i_1, i_2 = i.split()
            with open('short_1_double.txt', 'r') as short:
                for k in short:
                    k_1, k_2 = k.split()
                    w.poly(parts=[[[str(i_1),str(k_1)],[str(i_2),str(k_1)],[str(i_2),str(k_2)],[str(i_1),str(k_2)]]])
                    w.field('FIRST_FLD','C','40')
                    w.field('SECOND_FLD','C','40')
                    w.record('First','Polygon')
w.save('polygon')
```

При выполении скрипта, я получаю ошибку:

```
poly() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parts'
```

Как мне сохранить эти данные в `Shapefile` и исправить ошибку?

Если это может быть полезно, вот скрипт сохранения данных в geojson. Там все работает.

```
count = 0
file_is_empty = True
with open(final, 'w') as fin:
    fin.write('{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [')
    with open('long_1_double.txt', 'r') as long:
        for i in long:
            i_1, i_2 = i.split()
            with open('short_1_double.txt', 'r') as short:
                for k in short:
                    k_1, k_2 = k.split()
                    string = '' if file_is_empty else ','
                    string += '{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": ' +str(count)+'}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[['+str(i_1) + ',' + str(k_1)+ ']'+',' + '[' + str(i_2)+','+str(k_1) + ']'+',' + '['+str(i_2)+ ',' + str(k_2) +'],'  + '[' + str(i_1)+ ',' + str(k_2) +']]]}}'
                    fin.write(string)
                    file_is_empty = False
                    count+=1
    end = ']}'
    fin.write(end)
```

Вот результат geojson скрипта:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "area": 1
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [90.00526999999931, -0.004729999999999964],
                    [90.00553999999863, -0.004729999999999964],
                    [90.00526999999931, -0.004459999999999928],
                    [90.00553999999863, -0.004459999999999928]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "area": 81
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [90.00742999999386, -0.002569999999999677],
                    [90.00769999999319, -0.002569999999999677],
                    [90.00742999999386, -0.0022999999999996413],
                    [90.00769999999319, -0.0022999999999996413]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

Мне нужно точно те же данные, что и в geojson, только в Shapefile. Как правильно сохранить нужные мне данные в `Shapefile`?

В идеале, нужно считывать данные и записывать их построчно в Shapefile, так как данных очень много и все они не поместятся в оперативной памяти.

Спасибо)

P. S. Вариант при котором мы конвертируем `geojson` в `Shapefile` не подойдет, из за очень больших размеров данных :)

Answer (score 2):

Функция `shapefile.Writer()` ожидает на вход имя файла, вы же ей передали `int` - `shapefile.POLYGON`. Об этом и сообщается в ошибке.

Comment: спасибо, исправил ошибку.  Теперь возникла другая: poly() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parts'. Отредактировал тело вопроса, добавив нужную информацию

Comment: @ivan100096, я в документации не видел метода w.save() - где вы видели такой вариант использования?

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/Python%20Shapefile%20Library/ - вот здесь есть этот метод. https://prnt.sc/rob04v - вот скрин

Comment: @ivan100096, `"Revised: November 26, 2010"` - вас это не смутило? ;)

Comment: уже понял, работаю с новой документацией)